# How shoud I create an adaptive neuro fuzzy inference system (ANFIS) in MATLAB when I have a lot of inputs?

Tags: matlab, tools

In a fuzzy inference system, when the number of inputs increases, they usually either reduce the rules or, in order not to make mistakes, write the ruless between several nested systems, right?

For example, if we have 20 inputs, both of them form a fuzzy system and their output is the input of a new system, and so on until we reach the final output.

How can I make such a system with the MATLAB fuzzy toolbox?

Comment: `both of them` means `two of them` ... please edit your post if you meant something else ... did you mean to say, maybe, `all of them`?

Comment: Or did you mean pairs of them forming a tree to the final fuzzy output because of a limit to the number of inputs per node or a relevance to sequence in which nodes resolve?  Can't answer your question but if you only have two inputs per node the tree structure seems simple enough.  Try to be a bit more specific either to make it easy when the guy who can answer comes along or so that people with partially relevant backgrounds can help you out.  There are probably many more people who use matlab than there are people who use the fuzzy toolbox, and with the right information maybe can help you.